# How can I fix issue with my GULP workflow?

Tags: windows, npm, notifications, gulp, workflow

**Hello!**

I´m making gulpfile.js and I have this issius:

- gulp-notify doesn´t send notification to notification center
- gulp-clean-css show efficencie in %/100

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

    Gulpfile
    ========

    Impletation:
        1. Styles
            1.1 Sass to CSS (error catching)
            1.2 SourceMaps
            1.3 Autoprefixing
            1.4 Minify and rename
        2. JavaScripts
            2.3 Control witch JSHint
            2.1 Put it to one file
            2.2 Minify and rename
        3. Images
            3.1 Minify images (.PNG .JPG .JPEG .GIF and .SVG)
            3.2 Move
        4. Watch and sync
            4.1 Watching files
            4.2 Reaload browsers
        5. Build
            5.1 Export files to dist folder (only outputs)

    Conent:
    -------

        1. Project Variables
        2. Load plugins
        3. Browser Sync Setup
        4. Style Task
        5. JavaScript Task
        6. Images Task
        7. Watch Task
        8. Build Task

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

/*==============================
    1. Project Variables
==============================*/
/*
    Main
 */
var projectNAME = 'StartPlate'
var projectURL = 'startplate.dev/dev';

/*
    Styles
 */
var styleSRC  = 'dev/sass/**/*.scss';
var styleDEST = 'dev/css';
var minifySRC = ['dev/css/**/*.css', '!dev/css/**/*min.css']
const AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS = [
    'last 2 version',
    '> 1%',
    'ie >= 9',
    'ie_mob >= 10',
    'ff >= 30',
    'chrome >= 34',
    'safari >= 7',
    'opera >= 23',
    'ios >= 7',
    'android >= 4',
    'bb >= 10'
  ];

/*
    JavaScripts
 */
var jsSRC  = ['dev/js/**/*.js', '!dev/js/**/*min.js'];
var jsDEST = 'dev/js';

/*
    Images
 */
var imagesSRC  = 'dev/img/raw/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,svg}';
var imagesDEST = 'dev/img';

/*
    Wach
*/
var minifyWATCH = 'dev/css/**/*css';
var anotherWATCH = 'dev/**/*.{php,html}';

/*
    Build
 */
var buildDEST       = 'dist/'; // Files that you want to package into a zip go here
var buildSRC    = [
                // include common file types
                anotherWATCH,
                'dev/**/*min.css',
                'dev/**/*min.js',
                'dev/**/*.svg',
                'dev/**/*.png',
                'dev/**/*.jpg',
                'dev/**/*.jpeg',
                'dev/**/*.gif',
                'dev/**/*.ttf',
                'dev/**/*.otf',
                'dev/**/*.eot',
                'dev/**/*.woff',
                'dev/**/*.woff2',

                // include specific files and folders
                'dev/robots.txt',
                'dev/humans.txt',

                // exclude files and folders
                '!dev/img/raw/*',
                '!dev/**/*.scss',
                '!dev/**/*.map'

            ];

/*==============================
    2. Loading Plugins
==============================*/
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename')
var notify = require('gulp-notify')
var browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload       = browserSync.reload;

var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var cleanCSS = require ('gulp-clean-css');

var concat = require ('gulp-concat');
var jshint = require ('gulp-jshint');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var imagemin = require ('gulp-imagemin')

/*==============================
    3. Browser Synch Setup
==============================*/
gulp.task( 'browser-synch', function() {
  browserSync.init( {

    // For more options
    // @link http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/

    // Project URL.
    proxy: projectURL,

    // `true` Automatically open the browser with BrowserSync live server.
    // `false` Stop the browser from automatically opening.
    open: true,

    // Inject CSS changes.
    // Commnet it to reload browser for every CSS change.
    injectChanges: true,

    // Use a specific port (instead of the one auto-detected by Browsersync).
    // port: 7000,

  } );
});

/*==============================
    4. Styles Task
==============================*/
gulp.task('style', function () {
  return gulp.src( styleSRC )
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'compact'
        // outputStyle: 'compressed'
        // outputStyle: 'nested'
        // outputStyle: 'expanded'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe( sourcemaps.init( { loadMaps: true } ) )
  .pipe( autoprefixer( AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS ) )
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/maps'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest( styleDEST ))
  .pipe( browserSync.stream() )
  .pipe( notify( { message: 'TASK: "style" Completed! ', onLast: true } ) );
});

gulp.task('minify', function () {
    return gulp.src( minifySRC)
    .pipe(cleanCSS({
        level: '2',
        debug: true}, function(details) {
        console.log(details.name + ': old ' + details.stats.originalSize + ' kb');
        console.log(details.name + ': new ' + details.stats.minifiedSize + ' kb');
        console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.timeSpent + ' ms');
        console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.efficiency + '%');
    }))
    .pipe( rename( { suffix: '.min' } ) )
    .pipe(gulp.dest( styleDEST ))
    .pipe( browserSync.stream() ) // refresh
    .pipe( notify( { message: 'TASK: "minify" Completed! ', onLast: true } ) );
});

/*==============================
    5. JavaScripts Task
==============================*/
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src( jsSRC)
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(rename('index.js'))
    .pipe( uglify() )
    .pipe( rename( { suffix: '.min' } ) )
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDEST))
    .pipe( browserSync.stream() )
    .pipe( notify( { message: 'TASK: "scripts" Completed! ', onLast: true } ) );
});

/*==============================
    6. Images Task
==============================*/
 gulp.task( 'images', function() {
  gulp.src( imagesSRC )
    .pipe( imagemin( {
          progressive: true,
          optimizationLevel: 7, // 0-7 low-high
          interlaced: true,
          svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}]
        } ) )
    .pipe(gulp.dest( imagesDEST ))
    .pipe( browserSync.stream() )
    .pipe( notify( { message: 'TASK: "images" Completed! ', onLast: true } ) );
 });

/*==============================
    7. Watch Task
==============================*/
 gulp.task( 'default', ['style', 'minify', 'scripts', 'images',  'browser-synch'], function () {
      gulp.watch( anotherWATCH, reload);
      gulp.watch( styleSRC, [ 'style'] );
      gulp.watch( minifySRC, [ 'minify'] );
      gulp.watch( jsSRC, [ 'scripts'] );
      gulp.watch( imagesSRC, [ 'images'] );
 });

/*==============================
    8. Build Task
==============================*/
  gulp.task('build', function() {
    return  gulp.src( buildSRC )
        .pipe(gulp.dest( buildDEST ))
        .pipe( notify( { message: 'TASK: "build" Completed! ', onLast: true } ) );
  });
```

I try update npm & all dependencies and it doesn´t help.
toast.exe has allowed notification and in another project it works.

*Thanks for any help!*